# Displaying same pictures in getResources().getIdentifier()

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a music player app and I have some images in my drawable folder that want to show them in a particular order. I've found out that I had to use `getResources().getIdentifier()` methods but I got always same picture for all of my songs. So how can I solve this?
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( SingerListAdapter.SingerListViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    String drawableAddress = "R.drawable.gray_rectangle_"+i;
   viewHolder.singerName.setText(musicDataModel.get(i).getmAtrist());
   if(i != 47){
       int idResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableAddress,"drawable",context.getPackageName());
       viewHolder.singerMusicCover.setImageResource(idResource);
   }
   viewHolder.singerMusicCover.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_rectangle_5);
}
```

**NOTE** My `musicDataModel` variable contains all songs and their informations and works correctly.
And the same picture is always gray_rectangle_5

Comment: doesn't this line replaces previous `setImageResource`? `viewHolder.singerMusicCover.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_rectangle_5);`

Comment: @TouhidulIslam no it won't, the condition works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must drop the prefix `R.drawable` from the string `drawableAddress`, so change:

```
String drawableAddress = "R.drawable.gray_rectangle_"+i;
```

to:

```
String drawableAddress = "gray_rectangle_"+i;
```

Inside the `if` block you set correctly the image when `i != 47`, but when the code exits the `if` block it sets the image to `R.drawable.gray_rectangle_5` and this is why you always see this image.
Maybe you should add an `else` part to the `if` statement, assuming that this is the image that you want when `i = 47`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( SingerListAdapter.SingerListViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    String drawableAddress = "gray_rectangle_" + i;
    viewHolder.singerName.setText(musicDataModel.get(i).getmAtrist());
    if (i != 47) {
        int idResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableAddress,"drawable",context.getPackageName());
        viewHolder.singerMusicCover.setImageResource(idResource);
    } else {
        viewHolder.singerMusicCover.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_rectangle_5);
    }
}
```